# broken image icon is showing while rendering images of byte[]

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

So I am trying to display some reactive form data along with image that is coming as byte [] from asp.net core web api backend and I am using postgre for storage.

so I have angular application from where I am sending data as formData and I am converting IformFile Image into byte[] in "convertDataToImage" method and returning that byte[] to controller

Controller

```cs
[HttpPost("addData")]
public async Task<IActionResult> addPopulation([FromForm] FormData formData)
{
    if (formData.Image != null && formData.Image.Length > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(formData.Image.FileName);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "images", fileName);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await formData.Image.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }

        formData.ImagePath = filePath;
    }


    var b = new ByteImage();

    b.Area = formData.Area;
    b.Population = formData.Population;
    b.CountryName = formData.CountryName;
    b.ImagePath=formData.ImagePath;
    b.Image = convertDataToImage(formData);

    _context.SecondFormData.Add(b);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok();
}

[NonAction]
    public byte[] convertDataToImage(FormData Data )
{
    var b = new ByteImage();
    var Image = Data.Image;
    using (var stream= new MemoryStream())
    {
        Image.CopyTo(stream);
        b.Image = stream.ToArray();
    }
    return b.Image;

}
```

frontend:

```js
imageUrl: string = '';
    ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get<Data>(this.baseUrl + '/api/controller').subscribe(res => {
            this.data = res;
            this.filteredData = this.data;
            console.log(this.filteredData)
        });
        this.imageUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.filteredData.image;
        console.log(this.imageUrl);
    }
```

html

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let d of filteredData; let i = index;">
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td>{{d.area}}</td>
        <td>{{d.countryName}}</td>
        <td>{{d.population}}</td>
        <td>
            <button (click)="delete(d.id)">Delete</button>
            <button [routerLink]="['/change',d.id]">Change</button>
            <!-- <a (click)="delete(d.id)" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;">Delete</a> -->
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
            <img src="{{this.imageUrl}}" alt="Image" width="50" height="50">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

error:
[error that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE9XU.png)
kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

The res coming in api is in Array > object Format

And you are trying To access like this

**this.imageUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.filteredData.image;**

which is not Possible so it is Showing **Undefined**

You Can Try Below Code it Will Give You First image From Database

**this.imageUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.filteredData[0].image;**

Comment: Hi Jiten thankyou for your reply I am getting single image rendered as you have chosen only one this.filteredData[0].image .So in frontend it is showing only one image. any idea how I can iterate through response I am getting from api?      ``` ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get<Data>(this.baseUrl + '/api/controller').subscribe(res => {
   this.data = res;
   this.filteredData = this.data;
   console.log(this.filteredData)
   this.imageUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.filteredData[0].image;
   console.log(this.imageUrl);
  });
 }```

Comment: welcome , New answer has been posted You can change Your front Code

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to retrieve the data from server you need to wait till the request is completed.

Below code might work for you

```js
imageUrl: string = '';

ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<Data>(this.baseUrl + '/api/controller').subscribe(res => {
        this.data = res;
        this.filteredData = this.data;
        console.log(this.filteredData);
        this.imageUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.filteredData.image;
        console.log(this.imageUrl);
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Only Have To change Your Front Code To Display all Images Like Below

html changes

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let d of filteredData; let i = index;">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{d.area}}</td>
    <td>{{d.countryName}}</td>
    <td>{{d.population}}</td>
    <td>
        <button (click)="delete(d.id)">Delete</button>
        <button [routerLink]="['/change',d.id]">Change</button>
        <!-- <a (click)="delete(d.id)" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;">Delete</a> -->
    </td>
    <td style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
        <img src="{{'data:image/png;base64,' + d.image}}" alt="Image" width="50" height="50">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Jiten Patel contributor like you helps new coders a lot .

Comment: @user17596446 my pleasure to help you.